# Is it possible to link a Google Form to a desktop Excel sheet so that when someone fills in the form the data goes into the Excel sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, microsoft-excel

I work for a sporting organisation and track all sorts of monitoring variables using Excel spreadsheets. Up until now I have used macros in Excel to do this, but this requires players taking it in turns to do it on one computer and takes up a lot of time. To make it easier for the athletes I would like them to be able to access a form online and potentially fill it in on their phones. However the Google Docs version of Spreadsheets lack the functionality to analyse the data in the detail I would need to. Is it possible to link the Google Form up to an Excel document on my desktop so that when someone fills in the form the data turns up on the desktop sheet?

Comment: It's possible to publish a Google Sheet as a html or as csv file. Excel could connect to both formats, but that could be a matter of another site, like http://superuser.com. By the other hand there are APIs that could be used to get the data, but that could also be a matter of another site, perhaps http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, this is not possible, given Excel's incompatibility with Google Apps Script.

There is an alternate and only slightly less efficient solution, though: each time you want to analyse the results of your Form, simply download the connected Google Sheet as an Excel spreadsheet, open the downloaded spreadsheet in Excel, and do your analyses as per usual. To download the Google Sheet as an Excel file, go to **File -> Download as -> Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx)** in Google Sheets.

Comment: I thought that may be the case! Cheers anyway :)